# Assigning multiple groups of matrix entries to a constant value in MATLAB

Tags: matrices, matlab, math-software

Is there a command line in MATLAB that allows one to assign multiple matrix elements to $1$ or any other value?

For example, I set up a $40 \times 40$ matrix with entries $0$ everywhere except at

```
A(5:19, 1:4)=1
A(23:40, 6:7)=1
A(30:40, 15:40)=1
```

I would like to assign these elements in one command rather than multiple lines of code. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What about using semicolons? `A(5:19,1:4)=1; A(23:40,6:7)=1; A(30:40,15:40)=1;`

Comment: Thanks.That will work. I wonder if this is the only way to set up this matrix.

Comment: I think you can also write it as a $5 \times 5$ block matrix, but that would be much messier.